# Detect format of date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Currently we have multiple date formats in our database:

```
DD/MM/YYYY
DD-MM-YYYY
YYYY/MM/DD
YYYY-MM-DD
```

We all want to format these to one format `YYYY-MM-DD`. When using `dayjs` to do this I'm getting `NaN-NaN-NaN` back when running `dayjs('14/05/1993').format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

We can add a format to dayjs by adding the `customParseFormat plugin`

```
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat)
dayjs('14/05/1993', 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

But how can we detect the format for all four formats we have?

(Solution may be without `dayjs`)

Comment: Why not just match against of set of regular expressions and identify the right one?

Comment: `dayjs` also offers validation, so you should be able to run through the formats based on how they validate https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/is-valid

Comment: I would start by just replacing all `-` with `/` to halve your formats.

Comment: Just follow the [documentation](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format) -> _"If you don't know the exact format of an input string, but know it could be one of many, you can use an array of formats."_: `dayjs(..., [ "format 1", "format 2", ... ])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ### String + Format
>
> If you know the format of an input string, you can use that to parse a
> date.
>
> **This dependent on CustomParseFormat plugin to work**
>
> ```js
> dayjs.extend(customParseFormat) dayjs("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY")
> ```
>
> Pass the locale key as the third parameter to parse locale-aware date
> time string.
>
> ```js
> require('dayjs/locale/es') dayjs('2018 Enero 15', 'YYYY MMMM DD', 'es')
> ```
>
> You may specify a boolean for the last argument to use strict parsing.
> Strict parsing requires that the format and input match exactly,
> including delimiters.
>
> ```js
> dayjs('1970-00-00', 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid() // true
> dayjs('1970-00-00', 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid() // false
> dayjs('1970-00-00', 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'es', true).isValid() // false
> ```
>
> **If you don't know the exact format of an input string, but know it could be one of many, you can use an array of formats.**
>
> ```js
> dayjs("12-25-2001", ["YYYY", "YYYY-MM-DD"], 'es', true);
> ```

Source: https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format

With that...

```js
const possibleDateFormats = ["DD/MM/YYYY", "DD-MM-YYYY", "YYYY/MM/DD", "YYYY-MM-DD"];

dayjs('14/05/1993', possibleDateFormats).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: Oops. Must have missed that part! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem as long as your date format is consistent

```js
function dateFormatter(dateString) {
      
      if (dateString.includes('-')) {
            const splittedDate = dateString.split('-');
            if (splittedDate[2].length === 4) {
                 return splittedDate.reverse().join('-')
            }
            else {
                  return splittedDate.join('-')
            }


      } else {
            const splittedDate = dateString.split('/');
            if (splittedDate[2].length === 4) {
                 return splittedDate.reverse().join('-')
            }
            else {
                  return splittedDate.join('-')
            }
      }

}


console.log(dateFormatter('2020/15/5'))
```

Comment: Why use a custom implementation when all you need is an array?

Comment: @Andreas I didn't look at the documentation or the package. I thought the maybe package doesn't have the capability.